# How to set Blenderbot2 search server in google collab?

Tags: python, deep-learning, chatbot, parlai, blenderbot

I have a blenderbot2 notebook in google collab (https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ShpZlXMslxdS56OmNfvanqZT-3TRUuLf#scrollTo=u6BYFz39ynHF)

I run blenderbot2 using the following interactive mode

```
!parlai interactive -mf zoo:blenderbot2/blenderbot2_3B/model --search-server relevant_search_server
```

If you don't know, blenderbot2 is the latest deep learning chatbot from Facebook AI, which uses online internet search to keep its knowledge of the world up to date. I was able to run Blenderbot2, but it seems like anytime I ask a question, it would prompt the bot to search new information through a server and then causes a crash. The crash error message would be as follows:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='relevant_search_server', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fc85fbd1410>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
```

How do I configure the google collab notebook so that I can provide it the relevant search server?

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a Colab to use Blenderbot 2 if you want to try to talk with them. (note, you probably need Colab Pro and a P100 if not a V100, and high RAM set on for the 3B). There are 2 models to chat to, the 3B and the 400M, the 3B unconfirmed to run in Colab, while the 400M model does (with T4 and above) Just change in the last cell the command to use the 3B or the 400M model. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dSvIP63m4N3F2O8TMEHc2_z_fljUUk1m
(another note, it takes a while to run)

(also, if you want to talk to the original Blenderbot, use this Colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zNa7B4aWhjit03pNiVyXcvd99Il17IKb you need a T4 or above to interact with the 3B Blenderbot 1 model.)

Comment: Hi @faisal, i tried to go to the colab you linked and it said I need to request access. My server has a T4 in it so I think I should be able to run this locally. Just need the command to execute, just like the original poster...